Why did my optimization of compute shader cache hit ratio have the opposite effect?
I wrote a compute shader in ue4 that each thread needs to get the value of a structured buffer corresponding to its own id.As shown in the figure below, for example, my texture is 8x8, the thread group is 3x3x1, and the buffer is divided into the following blocks.
original structured buffer.img
My thought is that when the thread group id is 0,0,0, that is, the block in the upper left corner, when reading the buffer data, due to cache locality, 0,1,2 will be in the same cache line, but the following 8,9,10 and 16,17,18 are not in the same cache line, so it wiill read vram 3 times to get all the data, which brings about a delay in reading data. Therefore, I changed the order of the data in the buffer to the following .
changed the order of the data in the structured buffer.img
As shown in the image above, the data of each thread group is next to each other, so that the vram can be read once, and the cache will contain all the data needed by the current thread group. You can see that the data of thread group 0,0,0 was originally scattered, but now the data of this thread is arranged in order.
In my opinion, this can improve the cache hit ratio and thus reduce the time. But after I profiled with pix on windows, I found that the cache hit ratio of L1tex and L2 was reduced. The dispatch function cost time was also increased from 1ms to 4ms, which was contrary to my expectation. I want to know why this is happening? Is it because I don’t understand the GPU and compute shader well enough, or has the GPU done some optimization work on the structured buffer? This confuses me.Please help me, thank you very much

Honestly its not exactly clear to me what changes you have made, but GPU might prefer power of two thread groups, and depending on your shader optimal total number of threads can be within 32 to 256, and without flattening your dispatch/thread group you can only go like 8x8 and 1616(well actually also 84 etc), which is often optimal anyway. Its not hard to flat out thread groups, but it might have even worse performance depending on GPU/drivers. There is many factors and optimizing cache hit rate requires a lot of testing
